# How to accept a number between 0 and +inf

Tags: python, list

I'm just asking myself how I could create a liste with 6 number, but my first number is a integer 
and my 5 other number of my list are number between 0 and 100

Here, an example :

```
list=[5,(0,100),(0,100),(0,100),(0,100),(0,100)]
```

And for example, If I ask :   My list contains the number 45 ?

It returns me true !!

Thanks for reading me !!!!

Answer (score 1):

There is a special `in` keyword that let's you check if a list contains an element, like this:

```
'''    
check if element exist in list using 'in'
'''
if 45 in list :
    print("Yes, 45 found in List : " , listOfStrings)
else:
    print("No, 45 is not in the list List")
```

Of course, you should use a variable instead of the number to make the check.

You can find more examples [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-membership-identity-operators-not-not/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the python list data structure to create your list [[documentation]](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html).

Two simple ways of creating a list are:

```
# Create empty list and append
list = []
list.append(*elementToAppend*)
```

or you could just initialize the list with whatever you want in it

```
list = [1, (0, 100)]
```

Regarding checking whether a particular number lies in the range of one of your list elements, you can for loop through your list (starting from the second element, as your first element is the count) and check whether the input is greater than the lower bound and lesser than the upper bound.

However, why would you want the count of the list as the first element? You could just do,

```
len(list)
```

to get the count.

Comment: Yes but in your list, do you have the number 50 or 60 for example ?